# Autolayout dynamic UITableViewcell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, autolayout

I have created UITableView Cell Dynamic height with use of Autolayout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Problem is that I use UImageView with height of 6 as separator.
I set UImageView Top space margin (Vertical Spacing with its above UIButton (Button 2)) but in some situation I do not need to use UIButton(Button 2)

How I can disappear my UIButton(Button 2) and how I can establish UImageView Top space margin (Vertical Spacing with the above UILabel (Country)) because I cannot use UILabel (Desc) in some situation where I do not need UILabel (Desc)

According to API,

(1) UILabel Desc needed and UIButton(Button 2) not needed

(2) UILabel Desc not needed and UIButton(Button 2) needed

(3) UILabel Desc needed and UIButton(Button 2) needed (both needed)

(4) UILabel Desc not needed and UIButton(Button 2) not needed (both not needed)

UIImageView (Separator) come at the end of cell details

UILabel (Name) Compulsory I need

UILabel (Desc) Compulsory I need

UIImageView(Separator)  Compulsory I need

Means, I want to make UIImageView(Separator) Top space margin (Vertical Spacing in best way so that I can see in all cell without any extra space between UILabel (Desc)

I have uploaded my project on below link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzWG9UMzM2MTV6cms/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: [Check](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/09/uitable-view-cell-dynamic-height-ios7.html) the dynamic cell height using auto layout tutorial. You can copy the `UIlabels` and `constraints` from there.

Comment: use your label 's no. of lines 0.

Comment: Show your layout design.

Comment: @ajay_nasa I Have already set all labels number of lines 0 
Sometimes 
(1) UILabel Desc needed and UIButton(Button 2) not needed
(1) UILabel Desc not needed and UIButton(Button 2) needed
(1) UILabel Desc needed and UIButton(Button 2) needed both needed

UIImageView (Separator) come at the end of cell details
Thanks

Comment: @Mr.UB here layout design image link Thanks
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzRHFmdWw2WEZraEU/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya Button2 Height is fix in some cell I need Button 2 and other cell I do not need Button 2

UILabel Desc size is dynamic but  in some cell I need UILabel Desc and other cell I do not need UILabel Desc

Case is below

(1) UILabel Desc needed and UIButton(Button 2) not needed

(2) UILabel Desc not needed and UIButton(Button 2) needed

(3) UILabel Desc needed and UIButton(Button 2) needed (both needed)

(4) UILabel Desc not needed and UIButton(Button 2) not needed (both not needed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this screen shot correct or not?

1> Button 2 doesn't need in first cell.

2> Desc doesn't need in second cell.

3> Button 2 and Desc both need in third cell. (First cell in Screen shot 2)

4> Button 2 and Desc both doesn't need.

> Download Project this link: https://github.com/BhadreshKathiriya/AutoLayoutSignin

[image]
[image]

Comment: nice perfect but I need same padding after
1> Button 2 doesn't need in first cell. Fox Ex 10 pixel padding between Description and UIImageView Separator
2> Desc doesn't need in second cell. Fox Ex 10 pixel padding between Lavel Country and UIButton (Button 2)
3> Button 2 and Desc both need in third cell. (First cell in Screen shot 2)
It is perfect
4> Button 2 and Desc both doesn't need. Fox Ex 10 pixel padding between Lavel Country and UIImageView Separator

Comment: which index after padding?

Comment: nice good work is there any solution on same padding in above 4 case

Comment: nice perfect but I need same padding after 1> Button 2 doesn't need in first cell. Fox Example 10 pixel padding between UILabel Description and UIImageView Separator 2> Desc doesn't need in second cell. Fox Example 10 pixel padding between UILabel Country and UIButton (Button 2) 3> Button 2 and Desc both need in third cell. (First cell in Screen shot 2) It is perfect 4> Button 2 and Desc both doesn't need. Fox Example 10 pixel padding between UILavel Country and UIImageView Separator

Comment: Please my screen shot edit that check all padding in 10 pixel. 1 screen shot check cell 1 and 2. 2 screen shot check cell 1(3) and 2(4).

Comment: Download project above link zip file declare.

Comment: Sorry bro i can not get your updated project above zip link i got my old project
can you create new download link otherwise send me on my email id anks.patel62@gmail.com
Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: me change your project.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the obvious solution of configuring several different cell layouts (each with its own own reuse identifier). Seems to me that would save you a lot of time in trying to figure out bizarre auto-layout issues.

Comment: Hi cbiggin thanks for your response
it is very glad for me if you provide better solution, continue
you can provide your solution. Thanks